# Why is "numpy.int32" not able to be printed here? (Using geopandas + python 3.9.5)

Tags: python, numpy, geopandas, python-3.9

Here is the relevant code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

#A shape file (.shp) is imported here, contents do not matter, since the "size()" function gets the size of the contents
shapefile = 'Data/Code_Specific/ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces/ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp'

gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)[['admin', 'adm0_a3', 'postal', 'geometry']]

#size
#Return an int representing the number of elements in this object.
print(gdf.size())
```

I am getting an error for the last line of code,
`TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not callable`

The main purpose for this is that I am trying to integrade `gdf.size()` into a for loop:

```
for index in range(gdf.size()):
    print("test", index)
    #if Austrailia, remove
    if gdf.get('adm0_a3')[index] == "AUS":
        gdf = gdf.drop(gdf.index[index])
```

I have absolutely no clue what to do here, this is my first post on this site ever. Hope I don't get guilded with a badge of honor for how stupid or simple this is, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`gpd.read_file`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html) will return either a `GeoDataFrame` or a `DataFrame` object, both of which have the attribute `size` which returns an integer. The attribute is simply accessed with `gdf.size` and by adding brackets next to it, you get your error.

`size` is the wrong attribute to use, as for a table it returns the number of rows times the number of columns. At first glance the following should work

```
for index in gdf.index:
    ...
```

but you're modifying the length of an iterable while iterating from it. This can throw everything out of sync and cause a `KeyError` if you drop an index and before you try to access it. Since all you want to do is filter some rows, simply use

```
gdf = gdf[gdf['adm0_a3'] != 'AUS']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is,

```
gdf.shape[0]
```

or

```
len(gdf.index)
```

I think the first option is more readable but the second one is faster.

Comment: WIthout any parenthesis it still gives the same error

Comment: Yes, sorry, I updated my answer